# Generating a valid P12 signing certificate for automatically

Tags: ios, macos, certificate

I'm trying to convert a CER file to a P12 file for iOS signing automatically (the conversion should be automatic too, I can generate a P12 in the GUI very easily). The process illustrated by adobe [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html) works when using the Keychain Access but when I use the command line approach I get a certificate that fails on build (even on the Mac).

Specifically this fails with: Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found

If I import this p12 file to the Keychain Access app it seems the private certificate is broken:

[image]

The private key usually points at my name but instead its a hex number so I'm guessing this is the part that failed.

Comment: Sorry - misread the question when I posted my answer about generating p12 files

Comment: Do you have the matching private key? CER files generally don't...

Comment: I'm guessing that is the problem but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The cer file I use works perfectly if I use the GUI to generate the P12 which means the private key is indeed on the machine, but I'm guessing something gets borked during this stage (see the screenshot above) the private key clearly is incorrect... However, since the GUI automagically installs the private key from the login keychain I'm not sure why my command lines aren't working.